# how to parse json in bash script as an array? array value should have both key:value format

Tags: arrays, json, bash, sed, jq

my json.file looks like

```
{
  "price1" : "120.10",
  "price2" : "110.30",
  "price3" : "244.45"
}
```

I have used below sed command in my bash script to declare array that reads from json

```
array=( $(sed -n '/{/,/}/{s/[^:]*:[^"]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1/p;}' json.file) )
```

this gave me output for `echo ${array[*]}` values

```
120.10 110.10 244.45
```

I am looking for my array values to include the key name as well (`key:value`).
my desired output should be `key:value` format

```
price1:120.10 price2:110.10 price3:244.45
```

can someone please help or guide me?

Comment: Your input is not valid JSON, did you mean to have `{"price1":"120.10","price2":"110.30","price3":"244.45"}`

Comment: ah yes. my bad you are right. thats the correct format i have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing `json` with `sed` is probably a bad idea. But let's assume it is a super-simple and regular kind of `json` format. You were not too far from a working solution:

```
$ array=($(sed -nr 's/.*"(.*)".*"(.*)".*/\1:\2/p' json.file))
$ echo ${array[*]}
price1:120.10 price2:110.30 price3:244.45
```

The `p` flag of the substitute command tells sed to print the result if there was a match. It is good to know. If you have only two quoted strings per line of interest it should work. The regular expression `.*"(.*)".*"(.*)".*` matches anything - `.*` - followed by a double quote, anything again, another double quote... The parentheses - `(.*)` - do not change what is matched. It just records the matched part between parentheses in one of nine buffers that can be used in the replacement string - `\1:\2`. So here, the replacement string corresponds to:

```
<first recorded match>:<second recorded match>
```

If you want to be more specific about the matching lines you can. For instance:

```
sed -nr 's/^  "(.*)" : "(.*)",?$/\1:\2/p' json.file
```

Also specifies that there are 2 leading spaces, that the colon is preceded and followed by one single space and that there is a optional comma after the last quote and before the end of line.

But there is also the much simpler:

```
sed -nr 's/[[:space:]",]//gp' json.file
```

that just removes all spaces, double quotes and commas, printing only the matching lines. And guess what? It is what you (apparently) want.

Anyway, remember that if your `json` files are more complex than what you show `sed` is definitely not the right tool.

Comment: When other users search SO it is always better to have clearly separated questions. So, please ask a separate question with a clear explanation of what you want, and a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: just trying to understand what part of sed command fetches keys only? supposing my output would be only the keys and not values from json

Comment: @gmpy1990 I do not understand. Did you delete a previous comment or did I comment on the wrong question?

Comment: i have deleted my previous question as you mentioned its a separate (unrelated question)

Comment: @gmpy1990 Oh, I see. OK, let me add some explanation about the sed regular expression to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
json='{"price1":"120.10","price2":"110.30","price3":"244.45"}'

array=($(jq -r 'to_entries[] | ( "\(.key):\(.value)")' <<< "$json"))
echo ${array[@]}
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
declare -p array

echo

array=($(jq -r 'to_entries[] | ( "\(.key):\(.value)") | @sh' <<< "$json"))
echo ${array[@]}
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
declare -p array
```

Output:

```
price1:120.10 price2:110.30 price3:244.45
price1:120.10
price2:110.30
price3:244.45
declare -a array='([0]="price1:120.10" [1]="price2:110.30" [2]="price3:244.45")'

'price1:120.10' 'price2:110.30' 'price3:244.45'
'price1:120.10'
'price2:110.30'
'price3:244.45'
declare -a array='([0]="'\''price1:120.10'\''" [1]="'\''price2:110.30'\''" [2]="'\''price3:244.45'\''")'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution just needs to extract the extra data:

```
array=( $(sed -n '/{/,/}/{s/"\([^"]*\)"[^:]*:[^"]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1:\2/p;}' <<< "$j") )
echo ${array[@]}
price1:120.10 price2:110.30 price3:244.45
```

Simpler looking solutions may work too, but I'm assuming that you wrote your pattern like that deliberately.

The key trick here is to enclose part of your pattern with escaped brackets `\(...\)` and then have a numbered substitution for each in the output part `\1`, `\2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For bash scripting, you might want to use an Associative array:

```sh
declare -A prices
while IFS=$'\t' read -r key value; do
    prices[$key]=$value
done < <(
    jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, .value] | @tsv' json.file
)
```

Then, inspect the array

```sh
declare -p prices
```

```
declare -A prices='([price1]="120.10" [price3]="244.45" [price2]="110.30" )'
```

or iterate over it

```sh
for key in "${!prices[@]}"; do
    printf '%s => %s\n' "$key" "${prices[$key]}"
done
```

```
price1 => 120.10
price3 => 244.45
price2 => 110.30
```